# How to insert data in only one type of Vector in template class?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I have a FileParser class as follows below. The class contains a public method which parses a vector of type T by parsing the data for respective files. The file path is passed as parameter. There are two files to read Operations.txt and SetupDuration.txt. To read the specific file I am comparing it with the string operations and setupDuration. The data is being parsed assinged to the class variables and pushed into the vector which was passed to the function.

```
template <class T>
class FileParser
{       
public:
    vector<T> parseFile(vector<T> vec, string filePath)
    {
        ifstream file;
        file.open(filePath);

    
        string operations = "Operations";
        string setupDuration = "SetupDuration";
        string str; 
        
        // if Operations is found in filepath execute this if statement
        if (filePath.find(operations) != string::npos)  
        {
            Operation op;            
            while (getline(file, str))
            {
                // parsing file data for operation file , didn't include code for it
                op.codeOne = "...."; //assigning parsed data
                op.codeTwo = "....";
                vec.push_back(op);
            }
        }
        // if SetupDuration is found in filepath execute this if statement
        else if(filePath.find(setupDuration) != string::npos)
        {
            SetupDuration sd;

            
            while (getline(file, str))
            {
                // parsing file data of SetupDuration.txt file , didn't include code for it
                sd.title = "...."; //assigning parsed data
                sd.body = "....."; //assigning parsed data
                vec.push_back(sd);
            }
        }          

    file.close();
    return vec;
};
```

In my main class:

```
int main()
{
    vector<Operation> operations;
    vector<SetupDuration> setupDur;
    string opFilePath = "./Operations.txt";
    string setupDurFilePath = "./SetupDuration.txt";

    FileParser<Operation> fp;
    FileParser<SetupDuration> sFp;
    operations = fp.parseFile(operations,opFilePath);
    setupDur = sFp.parseFile(setupDur,setupDurFilePath);
}
```

The problem that I am facing is when I push back to the vector it pushes back to both the vector meaning for pushing back into Operation op vector it also tries to push back into SetupDuration vector.

```
no matching function for call to 'std::vector<Operation>::push_back(SetupDuration&)
no matching function for call to 'std::vector<SetupDuration>::push_back(Operation&)
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Operation' to 'std::vector<SetupDuration>::value_type&& {aka SetupDuration&&}'
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'SetupDuration' to 'std::vector<Operation>::value_type&& {aka Operation&&}'
```

One way this can be solved is not to use the template class and make separate functions but I really want to know if this is possible with template class or not. Is there any way this can be implemented in a correct way?

Comment: If you have access to C++17 have a look at `if constexpr` in combination with `std::is_same_v`.

Comment: I think parseFile should be a template function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I am not sure if you really need to pass the vector by value as an input argument.

- If the vector is always passed empty then you can can also create it inside the class itself. I have assumed that for the following example codes.
- If you need to append to it then pass it by reference `std::vector<T>&`.
- Only if you need to create a copy of it then I would actually pass it by value (as you do) or as `std::vector<T> const&` and create a copy of it.

Secondly I am not sure if your class should be a template class or only the method `parseFile` should be templated.

Furthermore you might want to make the **method `static`** if you do not need the file parser class itself for creating the `std::vector<T>` and any of its non-static class members.

Anyways these are the probably best options you can solve the problem you encountered.

- If you can compile your code with C++17 you could rewrite your code to use **`constexpr if`** in combination with the **`std::is_same_v` type trait** from `type_traits` to look something like this:

  ```
  template <class T>
  class FileParser {       
    public:
      static std::vector<T> parse(std::string const& file_path) const {
        std::vector<T> vec = {};
        // Code for all templates goes here

        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,Operation>) {
          // Code for Operation parsing here
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,SetupDuration>) {
          // Code for SetupDuration parsing goes here
        }
        // else if constexpr ... Other template types...
        // else ... Error handling

        // Code for all templates goes here
        return vec;
      }
  };
  ```

  This avoids the compilation errors you have encountered. If you want to make sure that the `filename` still has this form you could add an assertion e.g. `assert(file_path.find("Operations") != string::npos)`.

  [Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/F1ZxwefZpEBU5bHh)
- If you do not need to template the entire class you could **specialise the method `parse` alone for said types** (Note: You can't specialise only a method of a template class!). This does not require C++17:

  ```
  class FileParser {       
    public:
      template <typename T>
      static std::vector<T> parse(std::string const& file_path) const;
      // Other methods and class members
  };

  template <>
  static std::vector<Operation> FileParser::parse<Operation>(std::string const& file_path) const {
    std::vector<Operation> vec = {};
    // Code for Operation parsing does here
    return vec;
  }

  template <>
  static std::vector<SetupDuration> FileParser::parse<SetupDuration>(std::string const& file_path) const {
    std::vector<SetupDuration> vec = {};
    // Code for SetupDuration parsing does here
    return vec;
  }
  ```

  [Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SxWpNlFfZdITOVwt)
- Alternatively you could write a **constructor from a file stream for each template type** so you actually replace the `while (getline(file, str)) ...` part with a parser `T::parse(std::ifstream&)` (for `Operation` as well as `SetupDuration`) so all type specific is handled by the class itself. I think from a point of software design this is the best solution:

  ```
  template <class T>
  class FileParser {       
    public:
      static std::vector<T> parse(std::string const& file_path) const {
        std::ifstream ifs {};
        ifs.open(file_path);
        std::vector<T> vec = T::parse(ifs);
        return vec;
      }
  };
  ```

  [Try it here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pfcc6XJGH61gt3YX).

  Depending on the form of the file you could potentially break down the file into smaller chunks containing information for a single element only (e.g. if a line corresponds to an element) and create a constructor from `std::string` for the classes `T(std::string const&)` which handles the parsing. In that case you could do something like

  ```
  template <class T>
  class FileParser {       
    public:
      static std::vector<T> parse(std::string const& file_path) const {
        std::ifstream ifs {};
        ifs.open(file_path);
        std::vector<T> vec = {};
        // Assuming a singleline per element regardless of the container type
        // If this is not the case you could split it up in chunks depending on the template with if constexpr
        std::string line {};
        while (std::getline(ifs, line)) {
          // Short for vec.push_back(T{line});
          vec.emplace_back(line);
        }
        return vec;
      }
  };
  ```

  [Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3RrrYzSoE4k8KKNU)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. Personally I think so implementing a parse type for each template is quite a neat solution and as already mentioned seems best solution from software design.

Comment: @waasss You are welcome. I agree if this is easily possible that is probably the cleanest way! Good luck!